# rename a file to "frameset.php" in a CI project, in phpstorm/intelliJ

Tags: codeigniter, intellij-idea, phpstorm

Today when i'm coding in my CI project, i renamed a controller "dashborad.php" to "frameset.php", and i checked “search for reference”.
Then all files icon named "frameset.php" in my project became to a plain text icon and code assistant does not work.
How can i fix it?

Comment: Simple rename (from .php to .php) would **never** do that. You had to do something else as well (for example: "dashboard.php -> frameset -> frameset.php"). **In any case**: `Settings | File Types | Text files` -- find and delete unwanted pattern there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for @LazyOne's answer.
I remembered i do rename the "dashborad.php" to "frameset"(without .php) before.
That's work for me:

> Settings | File Types | Text files

Scroll to bottom, find and remove "frameset.php" in the "Registered Patterns".